# Parse login with Titanium

Tags: javascript, titanium, appcelerator

I've made a function where you can create a user on parse.com using Titanium, but i have trouble with the login part.
My code looks like this:
I get error code = 404; error = "HTTP error"; soruce = "[object TiNetwirkClient]"; success = 0; type = error;.

Any clue how to solve this?

```
btn_login = Ti.UI.createButton({
    title:"LOGIN",
    bottom: 170,
});

btn_login.addEventListener("click", function(e) {

    c = Titanium.Network.createHTTPClient();
    c.setTimeout(25000);
    c.onload = function(e) {
        Ti.API.info("onload");
        svar = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
        Ti.API.info(svar);
    };

    c.onerror = function(e) {
        Ti.API.info("on error");
        alert(e);

    };

    c.open('GET', 'https://api.parse.com/1/login/');

    c.setRequestHeader("X-Parse-Application-Id", "***************");
    c.setRequestHeader("X-Parse-REST-API-Key", "*****************");
    var params = {
        username:loginusername.value,
        password:loginpassword.value    
    };

    Ti.API.info("params" + params +loginuser);

    c.send(JSON.stringify(params));
});
win.add(btn_login);
win.open();
```

Comment: You are submitting username and password using JSON format.
Add proper header before sending request:

    c.setRequestHeader('ContentType', 'application/json');
    c.send(JSON.stringify(params));

Comment: True! it seams it was enough to type https://api.parse.com/1/login?username=xxxx&password=yyyy in open statement

Comment: Yup, so either you use JSON with proper header or URL Encoded values. Glad you figure it out.